# iphone (smartphones) css RWD rendering not working

Tags: css, smartphone

I made my site responsive using media queries and tested it by resizing my browser and it works fine. I also used a website to see how my page would render on apple devices, specifically iPhones, and the RWD worked. But when I looked at my site on an actual iPhones, or any other smartphone for that matter, it shows the page in "desktop mode"(i.e. not rendered with the media queries). Can someone please explain to me why this is? Sorry I don't have an example but I figured it's a common problem/fix. Thanks guys.

Comment: post your code, may be you missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind, as I've done it before, is did you forget your viewport tag?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Ah i did not do that. I assumed it might have had something to do with the meta tag. Thank you.