# CSS transform not working on smartphone

Tags: android, html, css, smartphone, skel

Website are using skel frameworks.

example : http://www.webdellarte.com/espace-client/ERA/

I tried on few smartphone and the same problem happend: the CSS **transform** looks like not working on smartphone
You can test on PC by deactivate the property transform (make window smaller to see the issue)

the blank space :

[image]

Is there any compatibility way with transform for smartphone? It seem that skel-layer.js is adding transform value inline.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried with another Android browser (Firefox, Chorme, etc) ?

Comment: Yes, it is not working on Android base. I tried galaxy S, some HTC phones  and Xperia Ray. Chrome seem to work but I need to fix it for everyone.

Comment: Which version of Android ?

Comment: This might help: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447372/iphone-smartphones-css-rwd-rendering-not-working